# Finding motivation learning guitar without a band

Tags: practice

I've been learning guitar for a year. Sometimes it can be really lonely practising without a band or someone to perform with. How do I find motivation to continue learning? Sometimes I'm envious of my friends who gig once a week or month.

Comment: Learn your favorite songs.. jam with your favorite band.

Comment: I'll not think performing for now but will be grateful that i could sit and play a couple of my favorite songs, and feel good with myself. I will start using backing tracks or compose a simple songs and use a software for the other instruments. I'll start motivating my sister to learn bass or drum, guess that could help. Thank for the response guys! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a teacher (you should !) ask them to set up a jam leading to a concert with the other pupils. Even if they are all at different levels, it won't matter. The teacher should be able to give appropriate parts to each. Suggest song you would like to do. Backing tracks are readily available on the 'net, so use some of these to play along to - they're more friendly than a band, and you can stop them while you practise without them getting upset.You could even consider trying to teach a friend or sibling how to play, and then playing along with them. Actually teaching is one of the most effective ways of learning. Sounds weird, but it's true !

Comment: Excellent answer. Backing tracks are great, or you can even play along to songs you enjoy - ideally you should find something that challenges you. Teaching your friends to play other instruments is probably the most enjoyable - I put together a fairly cheap studio so that when people come over we can jam. Guests enjoy it, and they don't need to have previous experience to learn a few notes on a bass guitar or keys.

Comment: If there is a music school in the area they will have several bands for beginners. You might have to pay to join, but it's worth it. You don't just get people to play with, you get tutoring.

Answer (score 2):

Join a band ;-)

Try to find one where all the musicians are better than you - but not so much better that they wouldn't consider you (obviously).
Playing with better musicians will improve your own playing, & also provide the needed 'reason to play'.

Without being too mercenary about it, consider at all times whether you think this band is going to be the next big thing, or whether you will leave as soon as you are better than they are.

Then join another band, where all the players are better than you.

Rinse & repeat until happy.